# Print HTTP response body even if server returns 500

Tags: curl

I run curl in a Jenkins build to make an HTTP call to a servlet application for the purpose of end-to-end testing.

Here is my command:

```
curl --fail -s -v <target-address>
```

The call results in HTTP 500 with a JSON output describing the error cause when I access it with the browser. That is alright.

However, curl indeed shows me only the 500, it suppresses the response payload. This is a problem because  in order to figure out the reason I have to manually reproduce the request through the browser. I would want curl to print the response payload too.
Here is the curl output (some things omitted):

```
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] + curl --fail -s -v <target-adddress>
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55829a1a6f50)
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'foobar
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == foobar
...
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55829a1a6f50)
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] *   Trying 147.204.6.136...
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * TCP_NODELAY set
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55829a1a6f50)
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > 
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] < HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] < 
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * CONNECT phase completed!
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * ALPN, offering h2
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * ALPN, offering http/1.1
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * successfully set certificate verify locations:
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] *   CAfile: none
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z]   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] } [5 bytes data]
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] } [512 bytes data]
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * CONNECT phase completed!
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * CONNECT phase completed!
[2020-06-26T09:14:...
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * Server certificate:
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] * 
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] } [5 bytes data]
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > GET <target-adddress>
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > Host: foobar
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > Accept: */*
[2020-06-26T09:14:00.433Z] > 
[2020-06-26T09:14:10.659Z] { [5 bytes data]
[2020-06-26T09:14:10.659Z] * The requested URL returned error: 500 
[2020-06-26T09:14:10.659Z] * Closing connection 0
```

How can I parameterize curl to show me the response payload?
BTW, I use `--fail` to let curl return a return code <> 0 if 500 comes back because I need to react on that case in my Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

You **asked** for the payload to be suppressed with the `--fail` option! Remove that option and you'll get the full response...

Comment: I get your point, but it does not help me because when I remove `--fail` then curl does not  finish with a return code unlike 0. Why I need that: My Jenkinsfile invokes `curl` and stores its return code and reacts on that later on to distinguish whether the actual call to the servlet was successful. So what I would need is: Instruct curl to return a return code <> 0 and still show me the response payload.

Comment: curl does not offer a command line option for that, I would propose using `-w` and use a shell script to check the response code